# como puedo hacer que dependiendo de lo seleccionado en un droplist me guarde en una tabla diferente de la base de datos

Tags: sql, jsp

esta es la parte de el jsp en el cual hago las validaciones

```html
<%@page import="Consultas.DAO_FINALCOMPLE"%>
<%@page import="clases.FIANL_COMPLE"%>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    boolean Enviar = false;
    boolean Limpiar = false;
    boolean consultar = false;
    boolean Editar = false;

    if (request.getParameter("Enviar") != null) {
        Enviar = true;
    }
    if (request.getParameter("Limpiar") != null) {
        Limpiar = true;
    }
    if (request.getParameter("consultar") != null) {
        consultar = true;
    }
    if (request.getParameter("Editar") != null) {
        Editar = true;
    }

    String mensaje = "";
    String numinfo_infoFINALcomple = "";
    String tipo_info = "";
    String resul_infoFINALcomple = "";
    String subir_infoFINALcomple = "";

    if (request.getParameter("numinfo_infoFINALcomple") != null) {
        numinfo_infoFINALcomple = request.getParameter("numinfo_infoFINALcomple");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("tipo_info") != null) {
        tipo_info = request.getParameter("tipo_info");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("resul_infoFINALcomple") != null) {
        resul_infoFINALcomple = request.getParameter("resul_infoFINALcomple");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("subir_infoFINALcomple") != null) {
        subir_infoFINALcomple = request.getParameter("subir_infoFINALcomple");
    }

    if (Enviar) {
             if (numinfo_infoFINALcomple == "") {
            mensaje = "Dede ingresar el numero del informe";

        } else if(tipo_info == ""){

        mensaje= " Debe ingresar el numbre de la compañia";
        }
             else {
            DAO_FINALCOMPLE DATOS = new DAO_FINALCOMPLE();//dao
            FIANL_COMPLE miUsuario = DATOS.getID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE(numinfo_infoFINALcomple);
//entidad

            if (miUsuario != null) {
                mensaje = "el informe ya existe";
            } else {
                // si es int new integwr(el campo)
                miUsuario= new FIANL_COMPLE( numinfo_infoFINALcomple,
                        resul_infoFINALcomple,
                        tipo_info,
                        subir_infoFINALcomple);
                DATOS.nuevoInfoC(miUsuario);
                mensaje ="enviado";
            }
            DATOS.desconectar();

             }

 }
```

clase dao que hago la consulta esta es la idea que tengo que dependiendo a el tipo de informe me guarde en la tabla que tenga dicho nombre no se si la consulta si se pueda hacer así .

```
 public void INFO_PRELI(FIANL_COMPLE miUsuario) {


    try {
        String sql = "insert into  "+miUsuario.getTIPO_INFO+""
                + "VALUES (" +miUsuario.getID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE()+ ","
                + "'" + miUsuario.getRESULTADO()+ "',"
                + "'" + miUsuario.getSUBIRCOMPLE()+ "'"
                +")";

        Statement stm = ConexionOracle().createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DAO_INFO_PRELI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



}
```

esta es la clase entidades

```
public class FIANL_COMPLE {

 String  ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE;
 String RESULTADO;
 String TIPO_INFO;
 String SUBIRCOMPLE;

public FIANL_COMPLE(String ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE, String RESULTADO, String TIPO_INFO, String SUBIRCOMPLE) {
    this.ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE = ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE;
    this.RESULTADO = RESULTADO;
    this.TIPO_INFO = TIPO_INFO;
    this.SUBIRCOMPLE = SUBIRCOMPLE;
}

public String getID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE() {
    return ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE;
}

public void setID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE(String ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE) {
    this.ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE = ID_INFO_FINAL_COMPLE;
}

public String getRESULTADO() {
    return RESULTADO;
}

public void setRESULTADO(String RESULTADO) {
    this.RESULTADO = RESULTADO;
}

public String getTIPO_INFO() {
    return TIPO_INFO;
}

public void setTIPO_INFO(String TIPO_INFO) {
    this.TIPO_INFO = TIPO_INFO;
}

public String getSUBIRCOMPLE() {
    return SUBIRCOMPLE;
}

public void setSUBIRCOMPLE(String SUBIRCOMPLE) {
    this.SUBIRCOMPLE = SUBIRCOMPLE;
}
```

}

espero puedan ayudarme

muchas gracias

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Debes mejorar la redacción de la pregunta.

Comment: Si las tablas tienen los mismos campos, así como lo tienes se podría, ¿te sale algún error?

Comment: por favor evite usar solo mayúsculas :)